# grep, sed or awk pattern which is output of a command line

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, pip

I have two files  (file.1.test and file.1)

```
$ cat file.1.test
foo
bar
baz
pattern

$ cat file.1

foo

bar

baz

pattern

this

should be

printed
```

Saying that: 
-my command  1 prints out the unique pattern in a file.1.test :

```
$ cat file.1.test | awk '{print $1}' | tail -n1
pattern
```

-My command 2 prints will print all  the line after the matching pattern in a file.1

```
$ cat file.1 | sed -e '1,/pattern/ d'
this
should be
printed
```

Is there a way to perform these two tasks in only one command line ? Or is there any way to  sed, or grep pattern that was the output of a previous command  ?

Thanks in advance

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As it is, this question suffers from poor formatting, making it very hard to read and understand. Always take a look at your post in the preview section before posting and check if everything looks OK. Is the code properly [marked and indented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90408/316262)? Did you use enough paragraphs and [other formatting tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)? Please [edit] your question until it is easy to read and understand. Also read the article on [ask]. Well formatted questions have a higher chance of getting good answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed "1,/`cat file.1.test | awk '{print $1}' | tail -n1`/d" file.1
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick help. I have other concerns What about if my file1 was :
$ cat file_1 
>foo
bar
baz
>pattern
this
should NOT be printed
>next
this sequence should be printed
>next
this sequence should be printed
 
and I would  my command 2 would be : 
$ cat file_1  | sed -e '1,/pattern/ d' | sed -ne '/^>/,$ p'
>next
this sequence should be printed
>next
this sequence should be printed

Now , How put the How can I link  the command 1 and the command 2.

Thank you in advance

Comment: @DieunelDerilus: Have you attempted it?